# C# IOC and Request State in NancyFX

Tags: c#, nancy, tinyioc

I want to inject a class into my module using the IOC framework in NancyFX, and I want that class to have access to the Context, just like the module does.

How would I do that?

The module has a property called Context, that doesn't seem to be injected (nor should it be, as it is the request state)... how does that work, and is that thread safe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use the `DefaultNancyBootstrapper` as a base for your bootstrapper you register your dependency in your container on a per request basis by overriding `ConfigureRequestContainer`:

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(TinyIoCContainer container, NancyContext context)
    {
        container.Register(new MyDependency(context));
    }
}
```

If you use a different container, the implementation will differ slightly.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for the tip. I can get this to work. But I was hoping, there was some sort of assembly discovery, that registered everything that has a NancyContext in the constructor. Kind of like the application container does.

Comment: Alternatively you could register the NancyContext in the request container.

Comment: Registering NancyContext directly in the container doesn't work. But it was a good idea. I just wrapped the context, and registered the wrapper. That mean I only have to register the wrapper, and then everything else is done using the application container. Thanks for the input!